# Handle top left button on iOS9

Tags: objective-c, ios9

I have an application, and this application open an url in Safari. But if the user tap on the top left button to return to my app how can i catch this event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case, the solution is to  view controller register for the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notification. When this notification is sent, you can do the stuff needed.

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doSomeStuff) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];

   -(void)doSomeStuff
    {
    //handle what you needed
    }
```

Comment: user3275938@Glad to help you